# quantum library penny lane gives wrong results

Tags: python

in quantum physics if we have tensor product of two Pauli X it will be identity matrix, when examine this theory it does not work properly, here I two function for two qubit which I calculate expectation value of tensor product of X(0) X(1) X(1) which means X(0) (X(0) for qubit one, X(1) for qubit two), so both of them must return same result they didn't .

```
import pennylane as qml
dev3 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=2)
@qml.qnode(dev3)
def my_quantum_function(x, y):
    qml.RY(x, wires=0)
    qml.RY(y, wires=1)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliX(0) @ qml.PauliX(1) @ qml.PauliX(1))
print(my_quantum_function(10,5))
```

and

```
import pennylane as qml
dev3 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=2)
@qml.qnode(dev3)
def my_quantum_function(x, y):
    qml.RY(x, wires=0)
    qml.RY(y, wires=1)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliX(0))
print(my_quantum_function(10,5))
```

I am trying to understand why it does not go well, doesn't calculate correct result

Comment: This is a very specialized question, is there a forum for that product, or maybe tech support from the provider?

Comment: This might be a better forum already: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ Searching for "pennylane" there yielded 203 results and there are 75 questions tagged [pennylane](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pennylane) so you'd be in good company there.